# Trapezoid table in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make an IPA vowel diagram like this one:

[image]

I have made a table with 7 rows and 5 columns in HTML, but how do I **change the shape of the table to trapezoid** using CSS?

I know that it's possible to draw a trapezoid in a graphics editor and then use the resulting image as a background in HTML, but I'd like to do do this with pure CSS if possible.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables should be used for displaying tabular data, e.g. rows and columns. This isn't tabular data. You should consider a different medium to display the information, perhaps `svg` or `canvas`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css like this to make shapes and build the table. Is dont think there i an other way to be honest.

```
#trapezoid {
border-bottom: 100px solid red;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
height: 0;
width: 100px; 
}
```

next time try to show us what you DID try to get the result.

Comment: Your code doesn't answer my question as it only draws a trapezoid shape underneath the table and doesn't actually change the appearance of the table itself.

Comment: the fact that you get that result clearly explains your css experience. you have to build the table by yourself using the css.  as far as i know....there is no easyer way. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the closest that you can get with CSS is using some 3d perspective:

```css
table {
  transform: translate(100px, 130px) perspective(200px) rotateX(-40deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
td,
th {
  transform: rotateX(40deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```